# White stripe under image

Tags: css, pug

I am trying to make a webpage. It goes well, but there is something I don't understand. There are four images on the site, and under two there are white stripes. I'll try to enclose a picture about it. I hope somebody could explain why.

Another question:
Do you know of a site where you can upload the code and someone checks it and correct it? So i can learn from it? I know "time is money", so I don't want it for free.

```
include layout
   // PAGE-WRAPPER
   .page-wrapper
    a(href='strandok_planjka')
        figure.roombox
            img(src='img/strandok/planjka.jpg', alt='')
            figcaption
                .border.one
                    div
                .border.two
                    div
                h3 Planjka
    a(href='strandok_lukonie')
        figure.roombox
            img(src='img/strandok/image03.jpg', alt='')
            figcaption
                .border.one
                    div
                .border.two
                    div
                h3 Lokunie
    a(href='strandok_zrce')
        figure.roombox
            img(src='img/strandok/zrice.jpg', alt='')
            figcaption
                .border.one
                    div
                .border.two
                    div
                h3 Zrce
    a(href='strandok_babe')
        figure.roombox
            img(src='img/strandok/beach_babe2.jpg', alt='')
            figcaption
                .border.one
                    div
                .border.two
                    div
                h3 Babe beach
    include footer
// end: PAGE-WRAPPER
```

css:

```
.roombox {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0%;
    padding:0 0px 0 0;
    width:50%;
    max-width:100%;
    box-shadow:none !important;
    -webkit-transform:translateZ(0);
    transform:translateZ(0);
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:15px;

}
.roombox * {
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.roombox img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
    opacity:1;
    background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Images are of different heights that bottom is empty space, to fix match your larger image to the same size as the smaller one.

Comment: Try using plnkr, You can interact with your code online and allow others to use it. As far as the white stripes I would assume it is the image. https://plnkr.co/

Comment: What is that first section of markup? It's not HTML.

Comment: dear lamCavic! yes the images have different sizes but under the larger one (2048*1365) is the stripe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone mentioned in the comments, I think it's because your images have different aspect ratios (size). Try either pairing images of similar sizes or, if you want the images to be altered to fit, remove the `max-width` and `max-height` and just specify `height: 100%;`, so width adjusts accordingly.

```
.roombox img {
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
    opacity:1;
    background-size: cover;
```